# Azure media service live stream how to implement stream from android app

Tags: java, android, azure, live-streaming, azure-media-services

I am trying to find any code sample on live streaming in java. 
I want implement it in an android app by azure media service. 
currently I have MediaRecorder instance which configured like this:

```
    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mServiceCamera);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);

        public String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/video.mp4";

        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(filePath);
```

I searched way to integrate with azure media service in my app to broadcast live streaming to cloud and delivery link to the stream in push notification to other app 
I exposed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-java-how-to-use) . the dependency there is not valid in android gradle file. how we need to work with that? 
also does need to use RTMP? or because the file content was saved directly in asset file in the azure storage it is doing the job? 
how much I am understood the locator create endpoint. 
can I get this endpoint url in the app for send it or it is existing only in azure portal? 
is the broadcaster need to be user in AAD? 
does it possible to give the user in the app the  ability to create credentials?

Answer (score 0):

I’m no Java expert but from what I’ve read about MediaRecorder it does not have the ability to stream an output in the RTMP protocol.  The phone needs to act like a client and push the RTMP protocol to the AMS server endpoint.  I believe the MediaRecorder api only output mpeg 2 TS from what I see in the API Docs.

I’ve seen projects that re wrap the output from the MediaRecorder into an RTMP stream. See https://github.com/octiplex/Android-RTMP-Muxer as an example.  No endorsement by me.

For your other questions.

1. Never include your azure credentials in a mobile application!  You need to use a middle tier to do the work for your app.  That means you would build an api to talk to the app front end, and that api would call the backend services it needs.   In this case a simple Azure Functions app would be sufficient or you can build and host your api in any framework you like.  The credentials to AMS will be an AAD service principal client id and secret that needs to be secured in the mid tier for your api to use.  The api would then return information like the RTMP ingest url.
2. When you create a live event in the v3 api for AMS you get back an object that contains the “ingest url” endpoint. That has a RTMP://server dns name :1935 port .   This is the url you connect to.   Make sure you start the live event first of course before connecting.
3. I recommend testing with OBS studio first until you understand the flow of connecting to an RTMP server. Go through the [OBS studio tutorial in our documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/live-events-obs-quickstart)
   When going through that tutorial consider that the OBS studio is acting like your android app.
4. In your code for MediaRecorder I see you set the audio to AMR.   You need to use AAC LC audio format.  That is the only audio format that we support for ingest, and it is the most widely used format for HLS and Dash streaming. It will provide the most compatibility on delivery to devices and browsers.

Comment: thanks. do I need open port number 1935 in client side too? actually I have ingest url: rtmp://stlive-stmedianame-aaea.channel.media.azure.net:1935/live/fdda7e6a7bb4484f98211e572f4e49XX but  I not succeed to create connections by used in library. how I can ping this url? in command line is not work. thank you